# Not Getting reply From Bot while running the app on device -Using Brain Shop API Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit2, chatbot

[image]

**Why is my bot not responding**

---

Not getting reply from bot while running the app on a device. I'm using Brain Shop API Android Studio in my Android Studio. It doesn't show any error, but while I am running the app I send a message but didn't get reply from bot.

---

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatbot);
        chatsRV = findViewById(R.id.idRVChats);
        userMsgEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtMessage);
        sendMsgFAB = findViewById(R.id.idFABSend);
        chatsModalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        chatRVAdapter = new ChatRVAdapter(chatsModalArrayList,this);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        chatsRV.setLayoutManager(manager);
        chatsRV.setAdapter(chatRVAdapter);
        sendMsgFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (userMsgEdt.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(chatbot.this, "please enter your message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                getResponse(userMsgEdt.getText().toString());
                if(userMsgEdt.length()>0) {
                    userMsgEdt.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });



    }
    private void getResponse(String message){
        chatsModalArrayList.add(new ChatsModal( message,USER_KEY));
        chatRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        String url = "http://api.brainshop.ai/get?bid=166135&key=HutlT9ZgXWrPpz3o&uid=[uid]&msg="+message;
        String BASE_URL = "http://api.brainshop.ai/";
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RetrofitAPI retrofitAPI = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI.class);
        Call<MsgModal> call = retrofitAPI.getMessage(url);
        call.equals(new Callback<MsgModal>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MsgModal> call, Response<MsgModal> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    MsgModal modal = response.body();
                    chatsModalArrayList.add(new ChatsModal(modal.getCnt(),BOT_KEY));
                    chatRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MsgModal> call, Throwable t) {
                chatsModalArrayList.add(new ChatsModal("please revert your question",BOT_KEY));
                chatRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: try this:

While running the app on a device (or emulator?), I send a message but don't get reply from bot, and it doesn't show any error in my Android Studio logcat window. I am using Android Studio with Brain Shop API.

Comment: on both device as well as emulator

Comment: both device as well as emulatir

Answer (score 0):

me too i had this probleme you have just change the url from :
`String url = "http://api.brainshop.ai/get?bid=166135&key=HutlT9ZgXWrPpz3o&uid=[uid]&msg="+message`
to

```
String url = "http://api.brainshop.ai/get?bid=166135&key=HutlT9ZgXWrPpz3o&uid=uid&msg="+message
```

remove [] from uid

Answer (score 0):

add this line in the manifest file

```
<application>
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" 
</application
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```java
call.equals(new Callback<MsgModal>()
```

To:

```java
call.enqueue(new Callback<MsgModal>()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).